# Request quota increase for stack driver logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

We are considering using stackdriver logging.

Currently the write quota is 500 messages/second and 25 million messages/day ? How do I make a request to increase this quota ?

Regards,

Sathya

Answer (score 1):

You can request more quota (for all resources) via the console:

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?&usage=ALL

Click on the "*Request Increase*" edit button on the right, and then click "*apply for higher quota*" if you need more. This will bring you to a Google form that you need to fill out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this but for stack driver logging api the maximum seems to 50,000 per 100 seconds or 500 per second which is too less for our production system. is there anyway i can request to increase the limit beyond 50,000 ?

Comment: Yes, click "apply for higher quota" in the dialog box like in the screenshot!

Comment: i don't see this link for "apply for higher quota" in stackdriver logging api, but see this in "monitoring api"

Comment: There appear to be fixed upper limits. I'm running into a related issue where a mis-configured cluster burned through my quota. Google's response was something along the ways of "¯\_(ツ)_/¯ wait a day"